# Cant go through list using with

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In my template, i have:

```
{% with x=0 %}
                <div class="wow fadeInUp content-works"> 
                    <span class="text-title center" style="color:white">Previous Orders</span>
                            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                                <div class="card-content white-text">
                                    <span class="card-title">Order #</span>
                                    <p>${{ payment.}} - {{ user.first_name }} - {{ user.last_name }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-action">
                                    <a href="#">Link to somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
    {% endwith %}
```

Payment.x in this wont output anything (its a filtered database) but when i do payment.0 or payment.1, etc, it shows the data. In the end, i want to put this in a loop so it displays all the data from payment from 0 to the number of values in the filter. Any ideas why this doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - iterated with a for loop:

```
                <div class="wow fadeInUp content-card" style="margin-top: 0;"> 
                    <span class="text-title center" style="color:black">Previous Orders</span>
                    <table class="highlight">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th data-field="id">Price</th>
                              <th data-field="name">Date</th>
                              <th data-field="price">Name</th>
                              <th data-field="quantity">Quantity</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                    {% for payment in b.latest_event_list %}
                          <tr>
                            <td>${{payment}}</td>
                            <td>{{payment.date}}</td>
                            <td>{{payment.event}}</td>
                            <td>{{payment.quantity}}</td>
                          </tr>
                    {% endfor %}                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

my views:

```
 def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, '    Please Login First before accessing the Dashboard')
        return redirect("/student/login")
    user = request.user
    temp = Payment.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
    tempint = len(temp)
    a = Payment.objects.order_by('-id')[:tempint]
    a = a[::-1]
    b = {'latest_event_list': a}
    print a
    return render(request, 'student/dashboard.html', {'b': b})
```

(Put in a table format using materialize to look cleaner)